# Visual Studio 2022: There is no project properties provider for "Persistence = ProjectFileWithInterceptionViaSnapshot". Projects are not loaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, projects-and-solutions

I cannot load all projects from one visual studio solution because of an error.

> error  : There is no project properties provider for "Persistence =
> ProjectFileWithInterceptionViaSnapshot".

The solution was moved from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 to Microsoft VS Community 2022. It can be opened within VS 2019, but it cannot be opened within VS 2022.

Here are details of my environment:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.4.2
> VisualStudio.17.Release/17.4.2+33122.133 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.04084
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.4.326.54890 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.4.326.54890 Azure App Service
> Tools v3.0.0
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.4.326.54890 Azure Functions
> and Web Jobs Tools
>
> C# Tools   4.4.0-6.22565.8+53091686b435746d62a5df56abfab0e71203d83a C#
> components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
> Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
> Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> NuGet Package Manager   6.4.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
> For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> Razor (ASP.NET Core)
> 17.0.0.2246202+61cc048d36a3fc9246d2f04625988b19a18ab8f0 Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62207.28050 Microsoft SQL Server Data
> Tools
>
> TypeScript Tools   17.0.10921.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
> Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
> 4.4.0-6.22565.8+53091686b435746d62a5df56abfab0e71203d83a Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools
> 17.4.0-beta.22512.4+525d5109e389341bb90b144c24e2ad1ceec91e7b Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>
> Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2 AI-assisted development for Visual
> Studio.

Comment: I had the same issue after a clean-up but running a "Repair" in the Visual Studio Installer with a reboot fixed the issue for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: It resolved the issue, thanks. I suggest you could add your clue as an correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after a clean-up.
This is what I did:

- Running a "Repair" in the Visual Studio Installer;
- Perform a windows reboot;

this fixed the issue for me. I hope it helps!

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: This seems to be a odd and not frequent issue, there are many results online.

Comment: If the Repair didn't work, why don't you try uninstalling Visual Studio, reboot, then go to %AppData%  and delete (or rename) the "Visual Studio" folders :
"AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio"
"AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services"
"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio"
and then re-install Visual Studio again?
I hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't help me either

Answer (score 2):

If repair does not work! Please try

1. Check System Environment Variable
2. PATH Variable must be **C:\Program Files\dotnet** 
   not **C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet**

Comment: This was it for me, thank you. NOTES: 1. It was under System Variables. 2. `C:\Program Files\dotnet` was in list. 3. Had to remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` (was also in list, possible earlier install).

Comment: I only have C:\Program Files\dotnet but having same issue

Answer (score 0):

try to [revert to previous version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX75b.png) and update again to newest version

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me. Same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to remove docker-compose (dcproj) project from the solution and then re-add it by right-clicking on the project to add to docker compose -> Add -> Container Orchestrator Support. When it asks to override existing file(s) answer NO. It modifies solution (sln) and project file (csproj) and loads and runs the containers using docker-compose. I'm on VS 2022 (17.5.3).

Comment: I had the same issue after months again on a different solution that contains a docker-compose project. My answer above is still valid, however, a simple remove/readd docker-compose project from solution also fixes the issue.